# What extra do I need to do while using HttpSession with GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, jakarta-ee, httpsession

I read , to set a session attribute I need to put :

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

inside *appengine-web.xml* and also implement `java.io.Serializable.` *(though I don't understand the reason for this !)*

Following is one of the servlet that uses *HttpSession* :

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    if(userName.compareTo("user") != 0 ) {
        list.add("Wrong Username");
    } else if(password.compareTo("password") != 0) {
        list.add("Wrong Password");
    }

    if(list.isEmpty()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(session.isNew()) {
            session.setAttribute("UserRole", "PW :Admin");
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(900);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("abc/cpanel/PcPanel.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("SessionStatus", "JC"); // Just Created 
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("abc/cpanel/PcPanel_Login.jsp");
    }
}
```

After validating the username and password and entering the `if` block,request should be forwarded to *PcPanel Login.jsp* but it doesn't happen.Intead a blank page appears with the address of this servlet. But if I remove/comment all the session junk,it works fine.  Why does it happen ? Am I missing something or I making a mistake somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `isNew()`. `isNew()` is only true when session is first established = when user first lands on any of your pages.

See the answer to this question: [Session is NOT working - GAE/J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712910/session-is-not-working-gae-j)

Comment: In one of the situation,I want only that user who just validated the credentials,see the page.How should I do that ? A new session is created whenever a user logs in by validating his credentials.

Comment: No, sessions have nothing to do with authentication. Session is established when user first visits any of your pages. About your problem: when user is authenticated (=credentials validated) you should set some property in session, i.e. `session.setAttribute("authenticated", true)`

Comment: If I check for the attribute _authenticated_ after the user validates the credentials,it will work fine. But it will give me a `null pointer exception` (for the undefined attribute : authenticated) if someones directly accesses that JSP page.Instead of showing the visitor an error message by the server I want to redirect him to the login page.How should I approach this ?

Comment: Also, you can make a redirect in JSP page: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/redirect.html

Comment: code in jsp : `<% if( (Boolean)session.getAttribute("authenticated") ) { %> ....html and other jsp..then at the end.. <% } else { response.sendRedirect("login.jsp") %>`

Comment: the scriplet starts just after the <body> tag. If anyone directly tries to access this jsp page,NPE is bound to occur because _authenticated_ attribute is unknown for the session object.

Comment: Your `if` statement throws NPE when `getAttribute` returns null. You should test like this: `if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(session.getAttribute("authenticated")))`